# TypeError: points.map is not a function at addressPointstoMarkers using AngularJS Leaflet Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I am trying to load and cluster markers from a geojson file using AngularJS leaflet directive. However, I am getting an TypeError: points.map is not a function at addressPointstoMarkers. Below is my code:

```
  <html ng-app="myapp">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-leaflet-directive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/leaflet.markercluster.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/leaflet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/MarkerCluster.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("myapp", ["leaflet-directive"]);
        app.controller("AlabamaController", [ "$scope", '$http', function($scope, $http) {

            var addressPointstoMarkers = function(points){
                return points.map(function(ap) {
                    return {
                        layer: 'Alabama',
                        lat: ap[0],
                        lng: ap[1]
                        };
                    });
                };

            angular.extend($scope, {
                center: {
                    lat: 30.126597156,
                    lng: -90.5958157696,
                    zoom: 5
                },
                events: {
                    map: {
                        enable: ['moveend', 'popupopen'],
                        logic: 'emit'
                        }
                },
                layers: {
                    baselayers: {
                        osm: {
                        name: 'OpenStreetMap',
                        url: 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                        type: 'xyz'
                        }
                    },
                    overlays:{
                        alabama: {
                            name: "Alabama",
                            type: "markercluster",
                            visible: true
                        }
                }
            }
            });

            $http.get("data/alabama.geojson").success(function(data){
                $scope.markers = addressPointstoMarkers(data);
            });
        }]);

        </script>
        <title>Alabama</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="AlabamaController">
        <leaflet lf-center="center" markers="markers" layers="layers" event-broadcast="events" width="100%" height="750px"></leaflet>    
    </div

  </body>
</html>
```

Here is a snippet of the data in the geojson file:

> [{"type":"Feature","properties":{"Name":"Drummond
>   Co Inc","Address":"1000 Urban Center Dr Ste
>   300","City":"Birmingham","State":"AL","Phone":"(205)
>   945-6300","County":"Jefferson","Latitude":"33.48360731","Longitude":"-86.70488291","BusinessDescription":"Coal
>   & Other Minerals & Ores -
>   Wholesale","SIC":"5052001","SICDescription":"Coal & Other Minerals &
>   Ores - Wholesale","NAICS":"423520","NAICSDescription":"Coal and Other
>   Mineral and Ore Merchant
>   Wholesalers","Website":"www.drummondco.com"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-86.70488291,33.48360731]}},

Comment: Please include the data you're getting from `data/alabama.geojson` URL.

Comment: @SinaGh I have added a snippet of the data in geojson file because the file is large.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you're getting is because you're calling the `map` method on the `points` object which isn't an array. The `map` method is only available on objects of type `Array`. You can check this by logging the `data` object your console: `console.log(data)`. Doing that, you'll see that `data` holds the response object of your `$http` method. The GeoJSON featurecollection object you're expecting is assigned to the `data` member of the response object. You'll need to change your `$http` success method:

```
$http.get("data/alabama.geojson").success(function(response){
    $scope.markers = addressPointstoMarkers(response.data);
});
```

Now `data` holds the actual GeoJSON featurecollection object. The array with features you need is stored under the `features` member of that object so you'll need to call map on that:

```
var addressPointstoMarkers = function(points){
    return points.features.map(...)
}
```

The method you've put in the `map` method is incorrect also. So it still won't work. It's expecting a flat object/array but it's getting a GeoJSON feature where the coordinates you need are stored under `point.geometry.coordinates`. So you'll need to change the method accordingly:

```
function(ap) {
    return {
        layer: 'Alabama',
        lat: ap.geometry.coordinates[1],
        lng: ap.geometry.coordinates[0]
    };
}
```

Now it should work as expected but i'de strongly urge you not to fix it this way. I suspect you've copy/pasted this from an example which uses a normal array of object for storing the coordinates. But you're working with a GeoJSON featurecollection for which the angular leaflet directive has perfectly good separate solution. Just assign your GeoJSON featurecollection to a member in `$scope`:

```
$http.get("data/alabama.geojson").success(function(response){
    $scope.geojson = addressPointstoMarkers(response.data);
});
```

And pass it straight to the GeoJSON directive of angular leaflet and you're good to go:

```
<leaflet geojson="geojson" lf-center="center" markers="markers" layers="layers" event-broadcast="events" width="100%" height="750px"></leaflet>
```

Simple as that :) Here's is a full example from the repository (there are more under the basic tab):

- http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/examples/0000-viewer.html#/basic/geojson-simple-example
  -